# how to search all list element in a column with filterMatchMode?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a table that show information like this :

[image]

when i search in REFARTICLE when the list have just less then 2 element he got me the result but when the column have more then 2 element the research didnt find the number searched :

thats my code

```
            <p:dataTable id="etatoutillage" value="#{dispoOTManagedBean.listOutillage}" var="item" emptyMessage="Aucun résultat trouvé" paginator="true" rows="15"  
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                    
                <p:column filterBy="#{item.technIdN}" style="text-align: center;" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Référence OT" />
                    </f:facet> 
                    <h:commandLink action="#{dispoOTManagedBean.modifier(item)}" value="#{item.technIdN}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column filterBy="#{item.refarticle}" style="text-align: center;" filterMatchMode="contains">
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="RefArticle"/>  
                    </f:facet>   
                    <p:dataTable var="aff" value="#{dispoOTManagedBean.returnarticle(item)}" > 
                       <p:column>   
                          <h:outputText value="#{aff}" styleClass="fonttheme" />
                      </p:column> 
                    </p:dataTable>  
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

how can i search all the element even if the column have many values ??

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem the solution is :

```
    <p:dataTable id="etatoutillage" value="#{dispoOTManagedBean.listOutillage}" var="item" emptyMessage="Aucun résultat trouvé" paginator="true" rows="15"  
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

        <p:column filterBy="#{item.technIdN}" style="text-align: center;" filterMatchMode="contains" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Référence OT" />
            </f:facet> 
            <h:commandLink action="#{dispoOTManagedBean.modifier(item)}" value="#{item.technIdN}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column filterBy="#{dispoOTManagedBean.returnarticle(item)}" style="text-align: center;" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="header">  
                <h:outputText value="RefArticle"/>  
            </f:facet>   
            <p:dataTable var="aff" value="#{dispoOTManagedBean.returnarticle(item)}" > 
               <p:column>   
                  <h:outputText value="#{aff}" styleClass="fonttheme" />
              </p:column> 
            </p:dataTable>  
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
```